# Linker cant find reference to a library function I know is there

Tags: c, linker

I have a library with some functions in it. Most functions work just fine but when I try to use one `memset_pattern12` the links fails:

```
CMakeFiles/kernel.dir/src/framebuffer.c.obj: In function `framebufferClearScreen':
/Users/user/Development/test/src/framebuffer.c:123: undefined reference to `memset_pattern12'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The library builds fine:

```
[  5%] Building C object CMakeFiles/myLibc.dir/src/libs/libc/malloc.c.obj
[ 11%] Building C object CMakeFiles/myLibc.dir/src/libs/libc/memcmp.c.obj
[ 17%] Building C object CMakeFiles/myLibc.dir/src/libs/libc/memcpy.c.obj
[ 23%] Building C object CMakeFiles/myLibc.dir/src/libs/libc/memset.c.obj
[ 29%] Building C object CMakeFiles/myLibc.dir/src/libs/libc/memset_pattern.c.obj
[ 35%] Building C object CMakeFiles/myLibc.dir/src/libs/libc/sbrk.c.obj
[ 41%] Linking C static library libmyLibc.a
```

and I can see the symbol in the resulting library:

```
nm compile/libmyLibc.a 

malloc.c.obj:
00000000 B heap_base

memcmp.c.obj:
00000000 T memcmp

memcpy.c.obj:
00000000 T memcpy

memset.c.obj:
00000000 T memset

memset_pattern.c.obj:
         U memcpy
00000000 T memset_pattern12

sbrk.c.obj:
         U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
         U __end
         U _get_stack_pointer
00000000 b heap_end.3627
00000000 T sbrk
```

There isn't anything special about `memset_pattern12`:

```
memset_pattern12(void *buf, const void *pattern12, size_t len) {
    char *start = (char *)buf;
    char *bufPointer= (char *)buf;
    while ((start + len) - bufPointer >= 12) {
        memcpy(bufPointer, pattern12, 12);
        bufPointer+= 12;
    }
    if ((start + len) - bufPointer != 0) {
        memcpy(bufPointer, pattern12, (start + len) - bufPointer);
    }
}
```

My CMakeList.txt:

```
set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O0" )
set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -g" )
set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -W" )
set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall" )
set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -nostartfiles" )
set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -ffreestanding" )

set( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-T,${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/etc/linker.ld" )

add_library(myLibc STATIC
  src/libs/libc/malloc.c
  src/libs/libc/memcmp.c
  src/libs/libc/memcpy.c
  src/libs/libc/memset.c
  src/libs/libc/memset_pattern.c
  src/libs/libc/sbrk.c
)

add_executable(kernel
  src/arch/arm/start.S
  src/cstartup.c
  src/kernel.c
  src/framebuffer.c
  src/platform/rpi/platform.c
  src/platform/rpi/rpi-irq.c
  src/platform/rpi/rpi-fiq.c
  src/platform/rpi/rpi-mailbox.c
  src/platform/rpi/rpi-watchdog.c
)

add_dependencies(kernel myLibc)

target_link_libraries(kernel)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And you *do* link with the library? What do your `CMakeLists.txt` file look like?

Comment: Are you sure that the linker actually gets `memset_pattern.c.obj` passed?

Comment: Updated question with CMakeFile.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
target_link_libraries(kernel)
```

you don't actually tell CMake to link with anything. You need to add the library here:

```
target_link_libraries(kernel myLibc)
```

If you do this, the dependencies will be set up automatically so you don't need the `add_dependencies` command.

Comment: I'm an idiot... but then how is it linking to `memcmp`? If I remove the code using `memset_pattern` it compiles and works just fine.

Comment: There is a C standard library memcmp, is that being called?

Comment: @Justin808 You don't tell the linker to not link with the standard C library.

Comment: I though `-ffreestanding` and `-nostartfiles` would prevent that.

Comment: @Justin808 You add those to the *compiler* flags, not the linker flags.

Comment: Thank you for all the help!